# Kontainer-di with Mongo Native

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get the [MongoDB Native Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/) to work with [Kontainer-di](https://github.com/redradix/kontainer). I want to add the connected client (returned from the connect method) to the container so that I can inject it into the controllers/services directly.

There is an option to use a `start` function which returns a promise which I thought would work with the mongo native connect function. The database is connected inside the `then`. My issue is that I'm not sure how I can access the connected database client to add the session to the container.

My code so far looks like:

```js
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var promise = require('bluebird');

var mongoFactory = function(config) {

    function start() {
        return mongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test", {promiseLibrary: promise})
            .then(function(database) {
                console.log('mongo connection initialised');
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.error('Error: ', err);
            });
    }

    function stop() {
        db.close();
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        stop: stop
    }

}

module.exports = mongoFactory;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody else has the same issue as me. I ended up going with the [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) library instead which doesn't use promises for the connection so the active connection could easily be added to the container.

I still wanted to use promises rather than callbacks for the queries so I used bluebird and it's `promisifyAll` method.